# ASP 5 MVC 6 HTTP Error 404.15 When deployed to IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been pulling my hair out trying to get Azure OpenID authentication working when hosted on a local IIS Server.

To test I have created a new web project and used the wizard to set up authentication with my Azure domain, all works perfectly on IIS Express, however when I try to run on IIS I get HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

If I remove Authentication All works fine.

I have been searching for hours but all the info seems to be pre MVC6, Any ideas what could be causing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had not setup the Authentication Secrets, seems that IIS Express stores them in file not included in your project, once added to appsettings.json all worked.